# Working with __get() by reference

Tags: php, properties, get, overloading, magic-methods

With an example class such as this:

```
class Test{
    public function &__get($name){
        print_r($name);
    }
}
```

An instance of `Test` will kick back output as such:

```
$myTest = new Test;
$myTest->foo['bar']['hello'] = 'world';
//outputs only foo
```

Is there a way I can get more information about what dimension of the array is being accessed, showing me (from the previous example) that the `bar` element of `foo`, and the `hello` element of `bar` are being targeted?

Comment: @Jan probably not when he's doing things by reference... I have no idea whether this is possible, but my strong suspicion is it's not. I'm pretty sure the getter will be used to fetch the *whole* array, and accessing one of its members will take place outside the getter.

Comment: @Jan; No typo, it is working by reference to permit multidimensional array element access for both setting and getting.
@Pekka; I was afraid of that. I tried setting a temporary variable to an empty string using what `$name` provides, in order to traverse the temporary variable for information, but that doesn't work as I hoped, giving me a temporary variable with only a single element with the `foo` key (based on my previous example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't with the current implementation. In order for this to work, you will have to create an array object (i.e.: an object that implements `ArrayAccess`). Something like:

```
class SuperArray implements ArrayAccess {
    protected $_data = array();
    protected $_parents = array();

    public function __construct(array $data, array $parents = array()) {
        $this->_parents = $parents;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = new SuperArray($value, array_merge($this->_parents, array($key)));
            }
            $this[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        if (!empty($this->_parents)) echo "['".implode("']['", $this->_parents)."']";
        echo "['$offset'] is being accessed\n";
        return $this->_data[$offset];
    } 

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if ($offset === '') $this->_data[] = $value;
        else $this->_data[$offset] = $value;
    } 

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->_data[$offset]);
    } 

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->_data[$offset]);
    } 
}

class Test{
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        $array['bar']['hello'] = 'world';
        $this->foo = new SuperArray($array); 
    }

    public function __get($name){
        echo $name.' is being accessed.'.PHP_EOL;
        return $this->$name;
    }
}

$test = new Test;
echo $test->foo['bar']['hello'];
```

Should output:

```
foo is being accessed.
['bar'] is being accessed
['bar']['hello'] is being accessed
world
```

Comment: Thanks netcoder; Your comprehensive example was exactly what I was looking for. I'll play with that.

Comment: Your answer here saved me again in my forgetfulness. I wish I could **+100** this - it's invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.
`$myTest->foo['bar']['hello'] = 'world';` goes through the following translation
`$myTest->__get('foo')['bar']['hello'] = 'world';` breaking them in parts become

```
$tmp = $myTest->__get('foo')
$tmp['bar']['hello'] = 'world';
```

What you can do is to create an `ArrayAccess` Derived Object. Where you define your own `offsetSet()` and return that from `__get()`

Comment: Thanks user256007; I'm guessing I can't pull the PHP generated temporary variable after it's been set to traverse in any way, can I?

Comment: Not only in PHP. in any language you can't pull a temporary variable generated by the `language` (Compiler|interpreter|processor). What happens in C++ is also the same we create an object and returns its reference or pointer. otherwise its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning an array, you could return an object that implements [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceArrayAccess.html). Objects are always returned and passed by reference. This pushes the problem at least on level down.

Comment: Thanks Oswald; both you and user256007 suggest `ArrayAccess`. I'll have to look into it, as I'm unfamiliar. Any suggestions on where I'd want to start with incorporating `ArrayAccess`?