# How to use __get() to return null in multilevel object property accessing?

Tags: php, php-5.3, stdclass

How can I use __get() to return null in multilevel object property accessing the case like this below?

For instance, this is my classes,

```
class property 
{

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return (isset($this->$name)) ? $this->$name : null;
    }
}


class objectify
{

    public function array_to_object($array = array(), $property_overloading = false)
    {
        # if $array is not an array, let's make it array with one value of former $array.
        if (!is_array($array)) $array = array($array);

        # Use property overloading to handle inaccessible properties, if overloading is set to be true.
        # Else use std object.
        if($property_overloading === true) $object = new property();
            else $object = new stdClass();

        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $key = (string) $key ;
            $object->$key = is_array($value) ? self::array_to_object($value, $property_overloading) : $value;
        }


        return $object;

    }
}
```

How I use it,

```
$object = new objectify();

$type = array(
    "category"  => "admin",
    "person"    => "unique",
    "a"         => array(
        "aa" => "xx",
        "bb"=> "yy"
    ),
    "passcode"  => false
);


$type = $object->array_to_object($type,true);
var_dump($type->a->cc);
```

result,

```
null
```

but I get an error message with NULL when the input array is `null`,

```
$type = null;
$type = $object->array_to_object($type,true);
var_dump($type->a->cc);
```

result,

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\test...p on line 68
NULL
```

Is it possible to return NULL in this kind of scenario?

Comment: The PHP language does not know about multi-level objects, objects are always a single node that knows nothing about it's ascending or descending node when accessed in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can return new property instead of null

```
 public function __get($name)
    {
        return (isset($this->$name)) ? $this->$name : new property();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, but it's not so trivial to explain how. First understand why you run into that problem:

```
$value = $a->b->c;
```

This will first return `NULL` for `$a->b`. So actually you wrote:

```
$value = NULL->c;
```

So instead of `NULL` on an unset item you need to return a `NULL`-object (let's namne it `NULLObect`) that works similar to your base class and that represents `NULL`.

As you can imagine, you can not really simulate `NULL` with it in PHP and PHP's language features are too limited to make this seamlessly.

However you can try to come close with the `NULLObect` I've describben.

```
class property 
{

    public function __get($name)
    {
        isset($this->$name) || $this->$name = new NULLObject();
        return  $this->$name;
    }
}


class NULLObject extends Property {};
```

Take care that this might not be exactly what you're looking for. If it does not matches your need, it's *highjly* likely that PHP is the wrong language you use for programming. Use some language that has better features of member overriding than PHP has.

Related Question:

- [Working with __get() by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4527175/367456)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Can I ask how to make an `NULLObect` in my script above? thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it actually makes sense for you, but I've extended the answer with a simple code-example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know it's been 4 years ago, but I had a similar problem this week, and while I trying to solve it, I found this thread. So, here is my solution:

```
class NoneWrapper
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->data = $object;
    }

    public function __get(string $name)
    {
        return property_exists($this->data, $name)
            ? new NoneWrapper($this->data->$name)
            : new None;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (is_object($this->data)) {
            return (property_exists($this->data, $name))
            ? $this->data->$name
            : null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}

class None
{
    public function __get(string $name) {
        return new None;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return null;      
    }
}

$object = new NoneWrapper(
    json_decode(
        json_encode([
            'foo' => [
                'bar' => [
                    'first' => 1,
                    'second' => 2,
                    'third' => 3,
                    'fourth' => 4,
                ],
            ]
        ])
    )
);

var_dump($object->foo->bar->baz()); // null
var_dump($object->foo->bar->third()); // 3
```